# Unable to connect to Cassandra from Airflow webserver

Tags: python, docker, cassandra, airflow

cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None')})

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information on how you've configured your environment to be able to help you in a meaningful way.

But the error indicates that your app is connecting to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) which means that you either didn't configure it correctly or that your configuration is not getting picked up so it defaults to `localhost`.

As a side note, if you've Cassandra to listen for client connections (`rpc_address`) on `localhost`, only apps installed on the same local server/VM. Any other apps running outside of that server/VM will not be able to connect. Cheers!